# AngularFireAuth create user with email without logging him in

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

Im using an angular application with firebase, and i have the feature that allows the admin user to create more users
this is the code im using in my AuthService

```
registerEmployeeByEmail(user: User, password: string): Observable<void> {
    return from(this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, password).then(credentials => {

      user.id = credentials.user.uid;
      this.db.doc(this.dbPath + user.id).set(user);    
    }));
  }
```

the problem is that right after the newly user is being logged in, the idea is not to log him in automatically...

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should use the [Firebase Admin SDK to create users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) with admin privileges. This will also avoid any throttling due to too many requests coming from the same IP address and prevents non-admin users from using this portal to create users too.

However, if you absolutely need this (and I don't recommend it), you simply initialize another FirebaseApp instance to create the users. That would keep the currentUser on the default Auth instance:

```
const app2 = firebase.initializeApp(config, 'tempApp');
app2.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)...
```

Comment: Do i need ro explicitly close the app2?

Comment: When you're done with `app2`, sign out the last current user and delete the `app2` FirebaseApp instance.

Comment: im still not clear on how to initiallize, on startup im using the following code inside my app.module.ts file AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig) but inside a service, i cannot use this code.what is the type of the firebase variable in your snippet?

Comment: I implement this on my service. On constructor I instance the new firebase: this.app2 = firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'tempApp'); -- And I import: import firebase from 'firebase'; -- then, you use it but with this.app2.... I write the code in the next response...